# Can 2 linq statements be made into 1?

Tags: .net, linq

I have 2 linq statements, below

```
// Extracts a list of int from List<BookmarkedDeal>         
IEnumerable<int> IDs = user.BookmarkedDeals.Select(d => d.DealId);

// Calls method to return List<Deal> using IDs from previous statement
IEnumerable<Deal> deals = DealBL.FindActiveById(IDs).OrderBy(d => d.Store.Name);
```

I think it's possible but I can't get my head around it at the moment.

Comment: I think your code is bogus. `int IDs` should really be `IEnumerable<int> IDs` and `Deal deals` should be `IEnumerable<Deal> deals`. Otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Daniel, you're correct. I changed them from var to help clarify but done the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the problem with this?

```
var deals = DealBL.FindActiveById(user.BookmarkedDeals.Select(d => d.DealId))
                  .OrderBy(d => d.Store.Name);
```

Comment: No problems Daniel, just starting out so the whole variety of ways linq can be used is overwhelming. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want to have an idea about how it would be doing the same with the query syntax:

```
var deals = from d in DealBL.FindActiveById(
                from d in user.BookmarkedDeals
                select d.DealId
            )
            orderby d.Store.Name
            select d;
```